# Is animation cancelling worth learning if you don't main AD carries?

Tags: league-of-legends

It's a game mechanic that takes many hours of practice to perfect, but is it worth it to learn if you're hardly using the AD carries in LoL?

Answer (score 4):

Sort of a tangent, but if you plan to successfully climb the solo queue ladder, you **will** have to play AD carries.  Not to mention that understanding the aspects of all lanes is essential regardless of which role you fill.

Animation cancelling is more prevalent in other games such as StarCraft:BW and DOTA, but it is still useful in LoL.  Basically it will reduce predictability in lane when you're last hitting as a ranged champion (generally mid and bot) as you're standing still for a fraction of the original animation time.

Personally, I come from a SC:BW background and animation cancelling is second nature so I didn't have to spend time practicing it, however all it takes is realizing how long the attack animation for each champion lasts.  Once you attempt to cancel it and fail a few times (by cancelling the entire AA and consequently its damage), you'll pick it up quickly.

Comment: I don't know, I find that by staying quiet in champion select you almost never end up with ADC... It's one of the most popular roles. Learning to play support well, on the other hand....

Answer (score 1):

I use it in any farming lane, not the jungle. I'd say its nice to know how to do if you want, otherwise dont worry about it.

Comment: Care to explain why the difference matters?

Answer (score 1):

Animation cancelling shows huge mechanical control. Learning it may improve your game in other ways. It is always good to learn new things. 
No it is not required but is a good way to gain more control over all characters