# What is the difference between automatic attack and attack-move-attack-move?

Tags: league-of-legends

What is the difference between automatic attack and attack-move-attack-move?
I mean, attack someone and just stand in my place and let the automatic attack do the work? or attack, move aside and attack again and so on?

Comment: If its a mob you don't really need to bother that much especially if they are not targeting you, but if you're in a fight with another champion, you want to dodge as much of their skilled attacks as possible.

Comment: [Related/possible duplicate](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/61991/attack-moving-or-attack-canceling)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The term for this is *Stutter stepping*.

This is a hugely important aspect of many games for several reasons.

The reason it is important is because moving doesn't affect your auto attack cooldown. So if you can attack every second, in between those seconds, you can move and it won't delay your attack. This mechanic allows you to move in between your attacks without lowering your DPS (if done perfectly, it's normal to reduce it slightly).

Now when you're attacking a melee champion for instance who is coming towards you, you can attack them, run away in this auto attack cooldown and then attack again. This allows you to get in more attacks before they reach you.

Similarly you can stutter step towards an enemy that is retreating in order to get more attacks in.

Another reason is that it allows you to reposition yourself. In a team fight position is hugely important, you don't wanna group too much with your allies or be too far away from them. So in order to not lower your dps, stutter step.

The final reason that I can think of off the top of my head is that it allows you to dodge attacks/ be more unpredictable. If you just stand there attacking the enemy will hit you with their skillshots everytime. You can reduce the chance of them hitting you by stutter stepping in any direction.

It's important to note that you can start to move before your attack animation has finished.

Comment: "The term for this is stutter stepping" - I've also heard it referred to as orb walking.

Comment: @MageXy Orb Walking is used in Dota as a way to attack the enemy hero w/o aggroing the creeps or the towers. It is only applicable to heroes with orb effects like Drow Ranger's Frost Arrow. It doesn't really exist in league although many players tend to jumble them up.

Comment: "It's important to note that you can start to move before your attack animation has finished" -- Note also that `may` cancel your auto attack sometimes.

Comment: @EtienneFaucher yeah that comes down to practice on that particular champ

Comment: I also like to point out about using skill with this. If you are standing in one place(auto attacking) your skill might not hit because of you showing that your about to skill. While attack-move-attack(kiting i believe?), you can hit multiple(if applicable) with your skills.

Answer (score 0):

### Attack Move:

- *Definition:* Your champion will move to the targeted location and attack the nearest in-range targets along the way. This is the traditional method used when kiting (though Attack Command can be used as well).
- *Execution:* Press 'A' and then left-click the target location that you want to move to/attack in. You can also shift + right-click the target location.
- *Benefits:* 1) When checking a bush that an enemy might be in you will automatically attack them if they jump out and 2) If you are kiting away from an enemy it makes for quicker movements because you right-click to move away then 'A' + left-click in the same location to have your champion turn and shoot, then right-click again to continue running.
- *Issues:* The main problem with this command is that your champion attacks the nearest target. If in a space where multiple enemies are present, you may attack the wrong target.

---

### Attack Command:

- *Definition:* Attacks targeted enemy unit. Champion will move to get in range.
- *Execution:* Press ‘A’ and then left-click on the target that you want to attack. You can also shift + right-click the target.
- *Benefits:* This command limits the penalty incurred when a miss-click happens. If you miss-click when using this command, your champion will simply attack the nearest target/wrong target. When you miss-click by using right-click for targeting, you end up walking into the enemy.
- *Issues:* Can take some practice to get used to. Technically is “one more button to press” than right-clicking. You can still miss-click and attack the wrong targets.

---

### Right-Click:

- *Definition:* Used to move your champion without attacking nearby enemy units. Can also be used to attack specific targets.
- *Execution:* Right-click on the location that you want your champion to travel to. Alternatively, right-click a target that you want your champion to attack.
- *Benefits:* Great for moving your champion without attacking any enemy units in range/along the travel path. Used in conjunction with Attack Move for smooth kiting.
- *Issues:* When using right-click to target and attack enemies, miss-clicking results in your champion walking into the enemy team. An out-of-position champion is often a dead champion.

---

All the execution hotkeys are based on default settings.

You can also smart cast both Attack Command and Attack Move (since they are both derived from the same click combinations). You can set "A" (or whatever works for you) to Attack Command/Attack Move wherever your mouse is currently located. The benefit from this is that you don't have to click with your mouse in addition to hitting "A." I don't personally use this but it's a personal preference.

Source: Reddit (Title: 
Attack Move, Attack Command, and Right-Clicking.)

Comment: This is nice but doesn't answer the question at all